# Copying a list of files dictated by a text file over scp to remote host, but says no such file or directory exists

Tags: bash, shell

I have several files in various sub-directories that I would like to scp over to a remote host using a shell script. I have a manifest text file with all the file names and paths listed. However, trying to run scp on every file in the list gives me "No such file or directory". I am using a Git Bash terminal on Windows 10.

The manifest.txt file with all the file names listed:

```
directory1/file1.elf
directory1/file2.elf
directory2a/file3.a
directory2b/file4.o
```

When I try to run

```
while read -r LINE; do scp ${LINE} root@<IP_ADDRESS>:/home/root; done < manifest.txt
```

I get `: No such file or directoryle1.elf` (on my terminal it appears that that the file name gets squished together with the error).

The odd thing is, when I run

```
while read -r LINE; do echo ${LINE}; done < test_manifest.txt
```

I get all the file names listed as expected (it matches the format of manifest.txt).

When I try to scp each file over individually, e.g. `scp directory1/file1.elf root@<IP_ADDRESS>:/home/root`, the file transfer works correctly, so I am wondering what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: `it appears that that the file name gets squished together with the error` -> make sure your file doesn't end with `\r`s (as it would if it had been created on windows), those characters might explain the mangled error message

Comment: You can check that using `cat -A manifest.txt` to display invisible characters. The lines should end with `$` which represents the `\n` unix linefeed, but these `$` should not be preceded by `^M` which represents the `\r` carriage return

Comment: And if that's indeed the problem you can fix the file with the `dos2unix` utility if you have it, or with `tr -d '\r'`otherwise

Comment: You can use `${LINE}` syntax to make sure the variable name gets recognized properly inside words like `blablabla${LINE}blablabla`, but it does not spare you the quoting, i.e. `${...}` does not prevent word splitting on substitution of `$LINE`.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's comment actually lead to solving the issue! Indeed I had originally created manifest.txt in Windows (I use Sublime Text). In Sublime Text, I changed View > Line Endings to "Unix" (from "Windows") and now the files copy over correctly. (Or as Aaron suggests, the dos2unix tool).

Comment: Glad to hear it ! Note that the mangled error messages are a typic symptom of `\r` where there shouldn't be, because in linux the character will actually be used as a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), so trying to print `error : file /path/to/your/file\r not found` will have the "not found" that comes after the `\r` written at the start of the line